# QEMU: How to disable guests access to public internet but preserve their access to local (samba) network drive?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, samba, qemu, shared-folders

I'm using `QEMU/KVM` for virtualization of various machines. For sharing files between the guest systems and the host system I run a `Samba`-server on the host which provides a network drive for the guest machines.

All guests receive their network via QEMU standard bridge `virbr0`.

---

**My question now is:**

How can I disable access to public internet for all guests **without** blocking their access to the `Samba` network drive?

Comment: Have you thought of a firewall rule?

Comment: I think you're asking to do with _QEMU/KVM_? I don't work with this, I only have virtual machines in _Virtualbox_, in this software I configure **two** network interfaces for each virtual machine, one for the network where I configure the gateway (you can only have one gateway per machine) and the other network where I'm posting the repos (without a gateway). If you don't configure a gateway you don't have a way to reach the "public internet" and still you have access to the `Samba` shared files. In this way you don't have to break your head with firewall rules.

Comment: For attention of other queue reviewers: I'm voting to keep this question open as this is clearly *not* a request for learning materials. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/22812

Comment: @k.Cyborg: Thank you very much for this great advice! I will have a try with a second network interface!

Comment: Don't worry about, only let me know if you solve your problem and if you want some ideas...Greetings and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you can use 9p, that works with `-nic none` BTW: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently needed to block internet access to a virtual machine (kvm-qemu + virt-manager).

When you launch the virtual machine you'll find yourself with the following iptables rules on your host (if you don't already have some):

```
$ iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

This configuration allows the virtual machine to access internet (FORWARD rules).
So what you want to do is delete the FORWARD rules:

```
$ iptables -L --list-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

$ iptables -D FORWARD 1
$ iptables -D FORWARD 2
$ iptables -D FORWARD 3
$ iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

This should actually suffice to block internet access to the virtual machine.
If you're paranoid you can block the samba port directly from the router (with the router interface, or if you have a shell access to it with the command line firewall).